# Trying to replicate a LaTeX front cover template

Tags: latex

I am trying to copy the following template:

[image]

Where I would like to replace the tiger with an image of my own but first I would like to replicate this one.

On the page below I have the LaTeX code but it does not work. I obtain a few errors (out of the box)

[image]

https://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Logos/logos

(Code is here^)

Are there any similar title pages where I can replicate the following?

Answer (score 2):

When I run the code it seems to work fine (except that the image of the tiger is missing), my compiler runs `LaTeX -> drips -> ps2pdf`, can TeXStudio do something similar?